# Ubuntu 16.04: Unity doesn't load basic GUI after login

Tags: unity, login, launcher, compiz, unity-dash

When I login I'm presented with only my desktop wallpaper.

Context menu works, I can open terminal and open other apps from there, but there is no basic things like dash and panel at the top.

The issue [looks similar to this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), however in my case GUI doesn't work only for a particular user, I have the second account which doesn't have this problem, it also works in guest session. I also tried applying [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/76951/710246) but it didn't help (when I rerun `ccsm` the Unity Plugin shown as switched off - may be that's the issue).

Last thing that I've done before the issue appeared was installing  updates offered by the system through UI.

To be more specific I have the following setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Linux 4.4.0-116-generic #140Ubuntu SMP
- Unity 7.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by resetting `compizconfig`.

The following commands:

```
mv ~/.cache/compizconfig-1 ~/.cache/compizconfig-backup

setsid unity
```

together with logout solved my problem.

**Attention:** This removes your custom Unity setup.